# How to asynchronously update React useState hook array

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm having order window which opens modal dialog for user to select multiple products to be added. On competition, all products are passed back by the callback function handleApplyModalClose. Within this function, for each product new item is created and sent to the API. On each response, I'm trying to update array orderItems with response data by calling addSavedOrderItem.

```
  const [orderItems, setOrderItems] = useState<OrderItem[]>([]);
  
  const addSavedOrderItem = (orderItem): void => {
    setOrderItems((prevOrderItems) => (
      {
        ...prevOrderItems,
        orderItem
      }
    ));
  };
  
  const handleApplyModalClose = (products, quantities): void => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    let count = 0;
    const expects = products.length;
    products.forEach((prod) => {
      const quantity = quantities[prod];
      const product = productSelector(productsState, prod);
      const { unitsPerCase } = product;
      const prodId: number = parseInt(prod, 10);
      const oItem = {
        product: prodId * 1,
        piecesPerBox: 0,
        quantityBoxes: quantity * 1,
        quantityPieces: quantity * unitsPerCase,
        transportPricePerBox: 0.00,
        transportPricePerPiece: 0.00
      };
      createOrderItemApi(order.id, oItem)
        .then((response) => {
          addSavedOrderItem(response.data);
          count += 1;
          if (count === expects) setIsLoading(false);

        }).catch((error) => {
          toast.error('Failed to save order!');
          count += 1;
          if (count === expects) setIsLoading(false);
        });
    });

    setIsProductPickerOpen(false);
  };
```

The problem I have is that when I try to update orterItems array in this way, component is throwing the error when I print out order items:

```
TypeError: orderItems.map is not a function
```

Comment: the function passed to `setOrderItems` should return an array, not an object. you can't call `.map` on an object literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
 const addSavedOrderItem = (orderItem): void => {
    setOrderItems((prevOrderItems) => (
      {
        ...prevOrderItems,
        orderItem
      }
    ));
  };
```

You are changing the type of your state from array to object, thus the error. I wonder why typescript doesn't scream about wrong data type

Comment: Oh, god. That was so naive mistake. Thanks for quick response.